# Is there a way to speed up PDF page merging (basically watermarking one with the other), when the base page is used repeatedly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pypdf

**Clarification: I don't want to add pages to a PDF file. I want to add content to a very big PDF page. The page changes sometimes and the content is different every time.**

I'm using pypdf2 and reportlab to make small additions to big PDF pages (~10MB).  This takes 30 seconds and more and the majority of that time is spend parsing the original.

Usually the page also needs to be turned using `mergeRotatedTranslatedPage`.

My idea was to generate the content array of the original once and then copy it every time I want to add something. So I modified `PageObject._merge` to do just that. It worked... kind of. I'm now down to 18 sec.

Is there a better way to speed up this process? 18 sec for one page is still pretty slow.

Comment: Do you mean *PDF files* by PDF pages? Or do you mean that the content streams of the PDF files are that big?

Comment: I have single page PDF files with up to 30MB size. Average is about 6MB. They are generally A0 / A1 and have a LOT of detail.

Comment: Added a clarification and changed the title to be more clear.

Comment: Okay, so if you only make additions, the content stream can be appended to. No need for parsing it as a whole. I don't know pypdf2 but look for something like an overlay feature that allows overlaying a page with some content. Rotating a page can be done with touching the content stream, by setting the /Rotate key of the page object. Both operations together should only take a few ms, the most time will be spent reading and then writing the file (but that's unavoidable).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **100%** capacity of all the cores of your **processor**, you can do it with "multiprocessing", as follows:

We count the number of pages in the PDF and the number of nuclei that your processor has, in order to calculate how many pages have to work  each nucleus has.

The pages that must work are sent to each nucleus and at the end all the PDF's are joined.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from io import BytesIO
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.colors import Color
from webcolors import hex_to_rgb
import base64
import multiprocessing
import math

class SkyMark:
    self.mainPdf=''
    self.mask=''

        #beginning, call from your api rest y pass request
    def begin(self,request):
        stringPdfBase64 = str(request.json['pdfBase4'])
        blob = self.workMultiprocess(stringPdfBase64,'MyWaterMark text')
        pdfbase64 = blob.decode('utf-8')
        return pdfbase64

    def workMultiprocess(self,stringPdfBase64,message='SkyMark'):
        try:
            #get pdf PdfFileReader objeto with your message
            self.mask = self.getMaskWaterMark(message)

            #Convert main pdfB64 to PdfFileReader object
            sanitizedPdf = stringPdfBase64.rsplit(',', 1)[-1]
            data = base64.b64decode(sanitizedPdf)
            stream = BytesIO(data)
            self.mainPdf  = PdfFileReader(stream , strict=False) 
            numPaginas = self.mainPdf .getNumPages()

            #count your cores of your processor
            coresProcessor = int( multiprocessing.cpu_count() ) or 22

            manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
            return_dict = manager.dict()
            jobs = []

            #calculate how many pages each processor has
            byPage= int( math.ceil( numPaginas/coresProcessor ))
            pagesFrom=0
            pagesTo=0

            #Send task for every core
            for i in range(coresProcessor):
                pagesFrom = pagesTo
                pagesTo = pagesFrom + byPage
                if pagesTo>numPaginas:
                    pagesTo=numPaginas
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.doByPage, args=(pagesFrom,pagesTo,i, return_dict))
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()

                if pagesTo>=numPaginas:
                    break

            for proc in jobs:
                proc.join()

            #Order single PDF's for merge
            randData = return_dict.values()
            ascArray = sorted(randData, key=lambda k: k['procnum']) 

            singlePdfsArray = []
            for pdfs in ascArray:
                singlePdfsArray.append(pdfs['dataB64'])

            #merge task
            return self.mergePdfsArray(singlePdfsArray)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error {e}')

    #Explotamos los cores del procesador
    def doByPage(self,fromPage,toPage,procnum,return_dict):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        waterMark =  self.mask.getPage(0)
        for i in range(fromPage,toPage):
            #print(f'WaterMark page: {i}, Core: {procnum}')
            page = self.mainPdf.getPage(i)
            page.mergePage(waterMark)
            page.compressContentStreams()
            output.addPage(page)

        letter_data = BytesIO()
        output.write(letter_data)
        letter_data.seek(0)    
        dataB64 = base64.b64encode(letter_data.read()) 
        return_dict[procnum] =  {'procnum':procnum,'dataB64':dataB64}     

    #Single Pdf with your watermark
    def getMaskWaterMark(self,texto):
        font_name='Helvetica'
        font_size=22
        color='#000000'
        opacity=0.08
        x=1
        y=840
        filename=''
        bgTexto='';
        for i in range(1, 6):
            bgTexto+= ' '+texto;
        
        cantidadRenglones=100
        mask_stream = BytesIO()        
        watermark_canvas = canvas.Canvas(mask_stream, pagesize=A4)
        watermark_canvas.setFont(font_name, font_size)
        r, g, b = hex_to_rgb(color)
        c = Color(r, g, b, alpha=opacity)
        watermark_canvas.setFillColor(c)
        print(watermark_canvas)
        for i in range(1, cantidadRenglones):
            watermark_canvas.drawString(x, y-(i * 25), bgTexto)

        watermark_canvas.save()
        mask_stream.seek(0)
        mask = PdfFileReader(mask_stream , strict=False)
        return mask

    #Merge all pdf in only one pdf
    def mergePdfsArray(self,arrayPdfsBase64):
        merge = PdfFileMerger()
        for f in arrayPdfsBase64:
            nada = base64.b64decode(f)
            stre = BytesIO(nada)
            src = PdfFileReader(stre , strict=False)
            merge.append(src)

        letter_data = BytesIO()
        merge.write(letter_data)
        letter_data.seek(0)    
        data = base64.b64encode(letter_data.read()) 
        return  data
```