# How to make watermarking multiple pages using PYPDF 2 more resource efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab, pypdf

I am trying to write a short script that numbers a 100page pdf (~100MB) which is the input file. I have made the watermark file which is ~60KB and am trying to produce an output that merges the 2 files page by page to produce the numbered output file. The watermark file was produced by reportlab which is just a 100 page blank document with the correct page numbers at the bottom (1,2,3,4,5, etc...)

Although the script works, it took 13 minutes to run using a mediocre quad core averaging around 30% CPU utilisation and 5.5GB of RAM use. This is way more than I expected since the generation of the watermark file is almost instantaneous.

The output file is also ~285MB which is way more than both the input file and watermark file combined.

The code is below:

```py
def mergepdffiles(inputfile,outputfile,watermarkfile):
    template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(inputfile, 'rb'))
    watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(watermarkfile, 'rb'))
    output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    for i in range(template.getNumPages()):
        page = template.getPage(i)
        page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(i))
        output.addPage(page)

    with open(outputfile, 'wb') as file:
        output.write(file)
    return None
```

I suspect there is a much more efficient way to do this in terms of processing speed and memory usage.

Alternatively, is there a more optimum way to add footers to each page in a multipage pdf without having to merge a two existing files? I would assume this would be more efficient.

Comment: _I have made the watermark file which is ~60KB and am trying to produce an output that merges the 2 files page by page to produce the numbered output file. The watermark file was produced by reportlab which is just a 100 page blank document with the correct page numbers at the bottom (1,2,3,4,5, etc...)_ Is it combining each pair of pages by placing one directly on top of the other?

Comment: I think so but I am not 100% sure how the PyPDF2 watermarks exactly but my assumption is that the white parts in the watermark pdf is set to full transparency and overlayed on the input pdf.

Comment: See, I thought the watermark PDF would already be mostly transparent. In any case, we were both thinking very similar things.

Comment: Sounds like we were essentially correct: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.mergePage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer will help you in [Is there a way to speed up PDF page merging...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363674/15635782) where the **compressContentStreams()** function is used that reduces the size of the pdf, and also uses **100% processor.**