# Is there a faster way to merge two files rather than page by page?

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm on Python 3, using [`PyPDF2`](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) and in order to add page numbers to a newly generated PDF (which I do using [`reportlab`](https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/)) I merge the two PDF files page by page in the following way:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def merge_pdf_files(first_pdf_fp, second_pdf_fp, target_fp):
    """
    Merges two PDF files into a target final PDF file.

    Args:
        first_pdf_fp: the first PDF file path.
        second_pdf_fp: the second PDF file path.
        target_fp: the target PDF file path.
    """
    pdf1 = PdfFileReader(first_pdf_fp)
    pdf2 = PdfFileReader(second_pdf_fp)
    assert (pdf1.getNumPages() == pdf2.getNumPages())
    final_pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    for i in range(pdf1.getNumPages()):
        number_page = pdf1.getPage(i)
        content_page = pdf2.getPage(i)
        content_page.mergePage(number_page)
        final_pdf_writer.addPage(content_page)
    with open(target_fp, "wb") as final_os:
        final_pdf_writer.write(final_os)
```

But this is very slow. Is there a faster and cleaner way to a merge at once using `PyPDF2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have enough 'reputation' to comment. But since I was going to post an answer I made it long.

Normally when people want to 'merge' documents they mean 'combining' them, or as you point out, concatenate or append one pdf at the end of the other (or somewhere in between). But based on the code you present, it seems you meant overlaying one pdf over another, right? Or in other words, you want page 1 from both pdf1 and pdf2 to be combined in to a single page as part of a new pdf.

If so, you could use this (modified from example used to illustrate watermarking). ***It is still overlaying one page at a time***. But, pdfrw is known to be super fast compared to PyPDF2 and supposed to work well with reportlab. I havent compared the speeds, so not sure if this will actually be faster than what you already have

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PageMerge

p1 = pdfrw.PdfReader("file1")
p2 = pdfrw.PdfReader("file2")

for page in range(len(p1.pages)):
    merger = PageMerge(p1.pages[page])
    merger.add(p2.pages[page]).render()

writer = PdfWriter()
writer.write("output.pdf", p1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You can use `PyPdf2s PdfMerger` class.

using file Concatenation, you can concatenate files using append method

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

pdfs = ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf', 'file4.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: This isn't merging the files, it's appending one after the other.

Comment: If you want more fine grained control of merging there is a merge method of the PdfMerger, which allows you to specify an insertion point in the output file, meaning you can insert the pages anywhere in the file. The append method can be thought of as a merge where the insertion point is the end of the file.

e.g.

merger.merge(2, pdf)
Here we insert the whole pdf into the output but at page 2.

Comment: Note: also that to avoid files being left open, the PdfFileMergers close method should be called when the merged file has been written. This ensures all files are closed (input and output) in a timely manner. It's a shame that PdfFileMerger isn't implemented as a context manager, so we can use the with keyword, avoid the explicit close call and get some easy exception safety.

You might also want to look at the pdfcat script provided as part of pypdf2. You can potentially avoid the need to write code altogether.

The PyPdf2 github also includes some example code demonstrating merging.

Comment: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/Sample_Code/basic_merging.py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer will help you in [Is there a way to speed up PDF page merging...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363674/15635782) where using **multiprocessing** takes **100% of the processor**